# Issue with rollover image in css and html when using a selection of different images

Tags: html, css

I have created a list of images on one of my web pages that when hovered over, it loses its opacity a bit and displays text over the top of the image. However, I can only get this to work through CSS meaning that I can have only one image linked to the class which means I have to have the same image see image below for a better illustration:

[image]

What I have tried is taking the image link out of the CSS and putting it into each list item, each with a different image (which is what I want). But then the image doesnt appear nicely within the border and the hover effect doesnt work, see image below for a better illustration:

[image]

Below is my HTML and CSS for the list (with the image link in the CSS and not in the HTML):

HTML

```
<ul class="imagelist">
<li class="rollover_img" ><a title="" href="">
<span>Bla Bla Bla </span>
</a></li>

<li class="rollover_img"><a title="" href="">
<span>Bla Bla Bla </span>
</a></li>

<li class="rollover_img"><a title="" href="">
<span>Bla Bla Bla </span>
</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.rollover_img {
width: 297px;
height: 150px;
background-position: top;
background-image: url(../images/homegallery/image2.png);
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border: 3px solid #7E9ED2;
font:13px normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:18px;
float:left;
margin:0 10px 18px 0;
}

.rollover_img a {
color: #fff;
width: 297px;
height: 150px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
}

.rollover_img a:hover {
background:#000;
opacity:.60;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}

.rollover_img a span {
display: none;
width: 280px;
padding:5px;
}

.rollover_img a:hover span {
display: block;
}

ul.imagelist {
width: 939px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 49px;
}
```

Anyone with any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `id` for each instance of `.rollover_img`, this way you can have a different background image in each list item.

Example HTML:

```
<li class="rollover_img" id="img01"><a title="" href="">
<span>Bla Bla Bla </span>
</a></li>

<li class="rollover_img" id="img02"><a title="" href="">
<span>Bla Bla Bla </span>
</a></li>

<li class="rollover_img" id="img03"><a title="" href="">
<span>Bla Bla Bla </span>
</a></li>
```

Example CSS:

```
#img01 { background-image: url('path/to/img01.jpg') }
#img02 { background-image: url('path/to/img02.jpg') }
#img03 { background-image: url('path/to/img03.jpg') }
```

Some tips:

- Try to have the same width for each image
- use `overflow:hidden` to hide those images that are too high for your container

Comment: Thanks, it works that way so I have decided to do it like that. Im sure there is another way to avoid having to do an ID for each image but they will do for now.

Answer (score 2):

In that case give `border-radius` to the image in css. I have included the below classin your css and remove padding:5px from the `.rollover_img a span`

```
.rollover_img a span img{
 border-radius:9px;
}
```

Check the demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/2zDKP/